# Duplicate values on the x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm having problems with this simple bar-chart graph in LaTeX.
Why are the years on the x-axis duplicated for values 2017 and 2018?
How can I have only 3 bars on the x-axis?

[image: bar chart]

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{eurosym}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

 \begin{document}   
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={2016, 2017, 2018},
        grid=both, 
        minor grid style={Gray!25}, 
        major grid style={Gray!25},
        ytick={-1954612.96, -3280597.68, 0, 2087865.92},
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        xlabel=Years,
        ylabel={Euro}
     ]
     \addplot[ybar, fill=Gray] coordinates {(2016, -1954612.96)(2017, -3280597.68)(2018, 2087865.92)};
     \legend{Bar value (\euro)}
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Another simple question: How can I write some custom data on the top-left corner instead of the(•10^6 multiplier)? I want to write something like "K€". Thank you in advance for every question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following lines to the axis options

```
xtick={2016, 2017, 2018},
ytick scale label code/.code={K\euro},
```

The first command sets the ticks for the `x` axis. The second command sets the label for the `y` scale. If you want to remove it, you can either leave the latter command empty, of you can use `scaled y ticks = false`.

[image: example image]